# Changing ssh keypair when creating an ec2 instance with chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I am bringing up an ec2 instance based on an in house AMI that used a different ssh key for authentication than the one I'd like to use on the instance I create using knife (in the example I call it original-pem-for-ami.pem):

```
knife ec2 server create  -I ami-0123456 -f m2.xlarge \
  --ssh-user username --groups sg-1234 \
  --identity-file ~/.ssh/original-pem-for-ami.pem \ 
  --node-name solr1 --hint ec2 -a public_ip_address \
  --ssh-key name-of-key-i-want-to-use-to-login-to-new-instance
```

When I run this command the server comes up correctly, the correct security group is assigned etc, but I can only connect it to using:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/original-pem-for-ami.pem username@assigned-ec2-public-dns-name
```

Is there a way to make the new instance the key associated with the named keypair `name-of-key-i-want-to-use-to-login-to-new-instance`. I thought using --ssh-key name-of-key-i-want-to-use-to-login-to-new-instance would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which version of `knife-ec2` you have. `--ssh-key` is correct in 0.12 but before that (0.11 and earlier) I think it was something different. Also make sure this works through the normal AWS tools, it is possible the AMI wasn't prepared correctly and uses a hardwired key.

Comment: The issue was the AMI wasn't prepared correctly. Thanks